How to quickly record the video of only one window in Windows?
I have run into a graphical problem in blender and want to record a video of only the blender window. I don't want to record the entire screen because the screen is very big (about three times the width of the blender window). How do I record only the one blender window in Windows?
The "best" way that I could figure out to do that is to record the full screen in OBS, open the file in Kdenlive (Video-Editor) and edit out everything out besides the blender window. This seems like a huge hassle for such a simple task (recording a single window).
Under Linux I would just open up SimpleScreenRecorder, tell it to only record the target Window by clicking on it and press record. I would have expected something similar in Windows, after all it has about 50x the user-base. I must be missing something here.
But the only solution I could find is payware, and I'm not willing to pay money for such a basic OS-feature.
I know that I could reduce the video capture resolution in OBS to fit the window, but not only is that also very cumbersome (how do I even know the exact resolution of the Window?) but even more importantly I don't want to screw with the OBS settings, otherwise I could run into Problems when I want to use OBS the next time and forgot to reset the settings.
Another thing I could do but don't want to do is use the OBS window-record function and scale the window-recording up to the full screen resolution in the OBS output window. But this will not only result in a huge video (with the resolution of my complete screen) but also result in a loss of quality due to scaling issues.
I feel like there must be an easier way to record just one window in windows. How do you people do that?
EDIT: I am looking for a solution that works on Windows 10.

Sorry, but what is the problem with OBS screen-capture object? You can double-click it to choose the other monitor. Regarding the settings: You can save presets to files or just use different scenes within the app. I'm voting for OBS

I don't know what you mean with "other monitor", I only have one big monitor. The problem with OBS is that it has a fixed recording resolution, I cannot change the recording resolution on-the-fly by selecting a window. When I record only one window in OBS, I get huge black bars left and bottom which I still have to edit out afterwards. Or I have to scale the recording of the monitor to the recording resolution which will result in a loss of quality / sharpness and a bigger video for no benefit.

Most 3rd party screenshot utilities that I am aware of do this easily.
Personally, I have used GetShareX to do this and it worked very well. With GetShareX you can record ad-hoc screen regions by drawing a box to choose the region, or you can record specific windows to capture an entire specific application's window.
You can adjust the application settings to your preferences regarding the video quality, save location, and other functions, then begin the recording using your preferred method.
I would give you a more detailed guide but I am not at a computer that has GetShareX at the moment, and, honestly, the process is quite simple and straight forward.

Thank you very much, this does exactly what I want (after figuring out the UI: The "record" function only does screenshots, but there is a separate "video record" function below; May be a translation issue). And it is even Open Source, which is a nice bonus. :-)

Yea, I really like the tool. It's so convenient and flexible. Lots of cool options, but also just captures stuff really quickly and easily.

The latest version of Microsoft's Snipping Tool can do video recording and you can select the region to record.
You just toggle onto video mode, hit 'New', then it lets you select the region and you hit record.
The version of Snipping Tool pre-installed with Windows might not have that functionality but the version from the Microsoft Store will: https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9MZ95KL8MR0L?ocid=pdpshare



Did not know the Snipping tool had this now. Cool. Do you know if Win10's Snip and Sketch has this function? Current Snipping Tool is Windows 11 only.

Huh didn't realize it installs a different version on Windows 10. It looks like the Appx Package in installs on Win 10 is:
Microsoft.ScreenSketch_10.2008.3001.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
While on 11 it's:
Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2405.32.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
You might be able to figure out a way to manually acquire the latter version, though I'm not sure how.

The description on the store page says this: "Note: The new Snipping Tool is available only on Windows 11. If you’re using Windows 10, Snip & Sketch will download to your PC instead." Snip and Sketch replaced the Snipping Tool in Windows 10, but everyone still called it the Snipping Tool. The tools appear to have some significant differences. I don't recall if Snip and Sketch had screen recording or if they left that function entirely in the Xbox Game Bar.

Looks like I already have the version from the Microsoft Store, and that version does not have video recording. So I assume that this solution only works on Windows 11, not on Windows 10.

This is also possible within OBS, although it's not the best tool for such purpose indeed.
Right click on the source -> Resize output (source size) and the output will quickly scale to whatever source you choose.
Then, to quickly reset to full resolution, click on the same option on Display capture type of source or change resolution in settings. Alternatively, create one profile for recording/streaming in full resolution and another for dynamic one where you'll click the resize option.
It's a bit clumsy compared to some other solutions, but has the advantage of keeping all the advanced setups you may possibly have within OBS.
